# Facebook "Like" button change to "Share" in FireFox

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share

I found funny problem - on FireFox (and only there) I see the Facebook Like button as Share. It's normal (becouse they merged Like and Share) or it's an issue? Somebody else has that problem? I found it on 2 computers. Is there any option to fix that?

Comment: My boss has found that with his account all "like" are showing as "share" on all devices he has tried.  I'm assuming there is some weird account related Facebook bug here.

Comment: I haven't resolved the issue, but I've filed a bug report with my steps to reproduce. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/423217227760752